# How to copy (and then delete) a row from sheet x to sheet y based on value in column 1?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working in Google Sheets and trying to set up an Apps Script macro that

1. Looks for rows in worksheet "Sheet1" that have the value "True" in column "A"
2. Copies this row and pastes it into the row below the last filled row in worksheet "Sheet2"
3. Deletes the row in "Sheet1"

I've been trying the code from another post on the forum but I keep getting: TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined. (line 20, file "Code")

Any help would be much appreciated

```
function copyrange() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); //source sheet
  var testrange = sheet.getRange("A2:AE990");
  var testvalue = (testrange.getValues());
  var csh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2"); //destination sheet
  var data = [];
  var j =[];

  //Condition check in G:G; If true copy the same row to data array
for (i=0; i<testvalue.length;i++) {
  if ( testvalue[i] == "TRUE") {
  data.push.apply(data,sheet.getRange(i+1,1,1,11).getValues());
  //Copy matched ROW numbers to j
  j.push(i);
 }
 }
//Copy data array to destination sheet

 csh.getRange(csh.getLastRow()+1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);

//Delete matched rows in source sheet
  for (i=0;i<j.length;i++){
  var k = j[i]+1;
  sheet.deleteRow(k);

//Alter j to account for deleted rows
  if (!(i == j.length-1)) {
  j[i+1] = j[i+1]-i-1;
}
}
}
```

Comment: "TRUE" !== "True"

Comment: @TheMaster thanks! I replaced the "TRUE" with "true" but i still didn't manage to make it work. maybe i missed something, e.g. is the above function looking in row A for the "True" variable?

Comment: "True" !== "true" either. Can you show what's in A:A screenshot?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/fVRCQPJ - here you go A:A - thanks for taking time to look at this!

Comment: Seems like boolean and not string.  Also, it's  a 2D array, you need to add a `[0]`. So, Try `if ( testvalue[i][0] ){...}` or `if ( testvalue[i][0] == "True") {` or  ``if ( testvalue[i][0].toString() == "TRUE") {``

Comment: If you're satisfied with cooper's answer, consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: Thanks for the help @TheMaster ! Just checked off Coopers answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function moveRows() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ssh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var dsh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var srg=ssh.getDataRange();//You might want to specify a more unique range. This just gets all of the data on the sheet
  var svA=srg.getValues();
  var d=0;//deleted row counter
  //I  assume one row for a header
  for(var i=1;i<svA.length;i++) {
    if(svA[i][0].toString().toLowerCase()=='true') {
      dsh.appendRow(svA[i]);//append entire row to Sheet2
      ssh.deleteRow(i-d+1);//accounts for the difference between length of array and number of remaining row.
      d++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this works like a charm - big thanks! how would i change the code if the conditional variable would change from "TRUE" to "yesTRUE" and the the variable's row would not be "A" but "AE"?

Comment: This `if(svA[i][0].toString().toLowerCase()=='true') {` would become this `if(svA[i][30]=='yesTRUE') {`.

Comment: Please checkoff the answer.  Thanks

Comment: done! new to this so didn't realize there was a checkoff. thanks for the help